# How to generate unique numbers in range 0001 - 2000 with rand() in C

Tags: c, random

I am trying to generate a dataset that has these two items: (i) a student ID containing values (0001 to 2000) generated from random and (ii) a corresponding age to the student ID (18 to 30). These random values are held in their respective **array[1000]** as you can see in *Code*

I am running into an issues with rand() where I have specified that I want to generate random numbers for the student ID from 1 to 2000 but I am running into what I think to be an issues of interger overflow. I think that the issues may be coming from one of the following:

- My function is of type *int*, I may need to try a different type?
- There is something wrong with the way I implemented my *rand() %* declaration
- Some other problem that I am not aware of

You can see the issue I am having in *Output*

*Code:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int createDataSet(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));             // generates the random numbers

    int i = 0, x, p, count;

    char arrayId[1000];      // array that holds the ID's of 1000 students
    char arrayAges[1000];        // array that holds the ages of 1000 students

    for (count = 0; count < 1000; count++) // Init the "age" and "id" arrays
    {
        arrayId[count] = rand() % 2000 + 1;              // ID range 0001 - 2000
        arrayAges[count] = rand() % (30 + 1 - 18) + 18;   // Age range 18 - 30
    }

    while(i<1000){
        int r=rand() % (2000 + 1 - 0001) + 0001;

        for (x = 0; x < i; x++)
        {
            if(arrayId[x]==r){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(x==i){
            arrayId[i++]=r;
        }
    }

    for (p = 0; p < 1000; p++)
    {
        printf("ID Number: %d       Age: %d\n", arrayId[p], arrayAges[p]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

```
ID Number: 115       Age: 28
ID Number: 104       Age: 21
ID Number: -113       Age: 25
ID Number: -3       Age: 18
ID Number: -41       Age: 20
ID Number: -94       Age: 28
ID Number: -4       Age: 19
ID Number: 4       Age: 28
ID Number: -112       Age: 23
ID Number: 33       Age: 20
ID Number: -119       Age: 30
ID Number: 12       Age: 23
ID Number: -96       Age: 27
ID Number: -88       Age: 30
ID Number: -105       Age: 20
```

My goal is to try and get the value in the array as seen in ID Number: to display random values between 1 to 2000 and be of unsigned type. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `(2000 + 1 - 0001) + 0001;` is a bit odd. `int r = (rand() % 2000) + 1` should give you random numbers [1, 2000]

Comment: Start by using `unsigned int` where appropriate.

Comment: `char arrayId[...` What does `rand()` return? How are you stuffing that into a `char`? Paying particular attention to [C11 - 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) and [C11 - 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you already have a good answer to your initial problem of attempting to assign and integer value outside the range of `char` to a `char` variable, there are a large number of small problems that remain unaddressed.

First, don't use **magic numbers** in your code. If you need constants, either `#define` them or use a global `enum` to define them, e.g.

```
/* if you need a constants, define them */
enum { MINA = 18, MAXA = 30, MAXS = 1000, MAXID = 2000 };
```

(where `MINA` is just short for `MINIMUMAGE` and `MAXS` for `MAXIMUMSTUDENTS`, etc.)

That way if you need to change a range or a limit, you have one simple location at the top of your code to make the change and you don't have to pick through all loop limits and variable declarations.

Next, your `return 0;` in `createDataset` is meaningless. If you have no value to return, and you are not doing anything within the function that requires a return to gauge success/failure, then declare your function as `void`. On the same note, the function may generate a dataset and print the values to `stdout`, but if the dataset is needed in the rest of your code, there is no way it can be used. Why? All your arrays `char arrayId[]..` are declared local to your function and the memory they are stored in is destroyed (release for reuse) when the function returns. You may want to refactor your code to declare the arrays in `main()` and pass the arrays, along with the number of elements to your function for initialization.

You can use this temporary storage within your function to your advantage in preventing duplicate IDs. You can simply declare a character array of `MAXID` length (say `char filled[MAXID] = "";`), initialized to all zeros and as each corresponding ID is generated, set the value at that index to `1` (or some nonzero value). That makes duplicate checks a simple test of `if (filled[r]) { /* regenerate ID */ }`

When you consider refactoring your code, you want to separate the function of each function into logical units. Your combined generate ID/age and output may fit your immediate needs, but consider separating the generating function and output into separate function.

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Putting those pieces together, you could refactor your current function into a separate generate and print function as follows:

```
void createdataset (unsigned short *ids, char *ages, int count)
{
    char filled[MAXID] = {0};           /* array preventing duplicates */

    for (count = 0; count < MAXS; count++)  /* for each student */
    {
        /* generate an ID */
        unsigned short r = (unsigned short)(rand() % MAXID + 1);
        while (filled[r])   /* while a duplicate, regenerate */
            r = (unsigned short)(rand() % MAXID + 1);
        filled[r] = 1;      /* set filled[index] to 1 */
        ids[count] = r;     /* assign ID to student */
        ages[count] = (char)(rand() % (MAXA - MINA + 1) + MINA);
    }
}

void prndataset (unsigned short *ids, char *ages, int count)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("ID Number: %4hu       Age: %2hhd\n", ids[i], ages[i]);
}
```

**note:** `srand` should only be called once in your code. So if you may potentially generate more than one dataset, it should be placed in `main()` to insure it is only called once.

When you are developing code that must meet special criteria, like IDs between `1-2000` and age between `18-30` consider writing a simple *validation check* that will verify all of your values are within range. For example here you could do something like:

```
int validateset (unsigned short *ids, char *ages, int count)
{
    int i = 0, err = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (ids[i] < 1 || ids[i] > MAXID) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: arrayid[%d] : %hu out of range.\n", 
                    i, ids[i]);
            err = 1;
        }
        if (ages[i] < MINA || ages[i] > MAXA) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: arrayages[%d] : %hhd out of range.\n", 
                    i, ages[i]);
            err = 1;
        }
    }

    return err;
}
```

(which will return `0` on success, and `1` if there is any value out of range after outputting any offending values)

Also, when you are printing values, make sure your *format specifiers* match the type of value you are outputting. While rules of promotion will handle converting smaller values (e.g. `short`) to `int` using the `%d` or `%u` format specifiers, if your compiler supports the `h` modifiers, they should be used to specify the proper output size (e.g. to print a `unsigned short`, use `%hu` or to print an `unsigned char`, use `%hhu`).

Putting all the pieces together in a short example, you could refactor your code and add a validation check with something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* if you need a constants, define them */
enum { MINA = 18, MAXA = 30, MAXS = 1000, MAXID = 2000 };

void createdataset (unsigned short *ids, char *ages, int count)
{
    char filled[MAXID] = {0};           /* array preventing duplicates */

    for (count = 0; count < MAXS; count++)  /* for each student */
    {
        /* generate an ID */
        unsigned short r = (unsigned short)(rand() % MAXID + 1);
        while (filled[r])   /* while a duplicate, regenerate */
            r = (unsigned short)(rand() % MAXID + 1);
        filled[r] = 1;      /* set filled[index] to 1 */
        ids[count] = r;     /* assign ID to student */
        ages[count] = (char)(rand() % (MAXA - MINA + 1) + MINA);
    }
}

void prndataset (unsigned short *ids, char *ages, int count)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("ID Number: %4hu       Age: %2hhd\n", ids[i], ages[i]);
}

int validateset (unsigned short *ids, char *ages, int count)
{
    int i = 0, err = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (ids[i] < 1 || ids[i] > MAXID) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: arrayid[%d] : %hu out of range.\n", 
                    i, ids[i]);
            err = 1;
        }
        if (ages[i] < MINA || ages[i] > MAXA) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: arrayages[%d] : %hhd out of range.\n", 
                    i, ages[i]);
            err = 1;
        }
    }

    return err;
}

int main (void) {

    unsigned short arrayid[MAXS] = {0}; /* size your type to your needed */
    char arrayages[MAXS] = {0};         /* range and enforce the range */

    srand(time(NULL));                  /* initialize random number seed */

    createdataset (arrayid, arrayages, MAXS);   /* initialize dataset */
    if (validateset (arrayid, arrayages, MAXS)) /* validate dataset */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    prndataset (arrayid, arrayages, MAXS);      /* output dataset */

    return 0;
}
```

(by adding the validation check, you can have confidence that if your code runs without displaying an error, the dataset was generated properly)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/createdataset > dat/dataset1.txt

$ head -n 10 dat/dataset1.txt; echo "..."; tail -n 10 dat/dataset1.txt
ID Number: 1049       Age: 29
ID Number:  743       Age: 21
ID Number:  915       Age: 22
ID Number: 1539       Age: 19
ID Number:  793       Age: 18
ID Number: 1166       Age: 21
ID Number:  372       Age: 28
ID Number: 1763       Age: 19
ID Number:  782       Age: 20
ID Number: 1490       Age: 30
...
ID Number:  186       Age: 30
ID Number: 1389       Age: 23
ID Number: 1630       Age: 22
ID Number:  432       Age: 27
ID Number:  240       Age: 24
ID Number:  152       Age: 25
ID Number: 1598       Age: 22
ID Number: 1408       Age: 24
ID Number:  834       Age: 24
ID Number: 1699       Age: 25
```

While your main issues was the storage of an `int` in `char` problem, there are many other more subtle issues to consider. Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `arrayId`  as **unsigned short array** because `unsigned char arrayId[index]` won't work as maximum in each `arrayId[index]` you can store only `255` but you want to store upto `2000`.

```
unsigned short arrayId[1000]; /* try to store negative number, cyclic flow will happen  */

unsigned char arrayAges[1000];
```

Comment: Umm... `int r=rand() % (2000 + 1 - 1) + 1;` cannot give a negative number. The range is `1-2000`? Perhaps you meant if assigned to a `char`?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));             

    int i = 0, x, p, count;

    unsigned arrayId[1000];   //You Can USE :unsigned int or unsigned short 
    char arrayAges[1000];     

    for (count = 0; count < 1000; count++) 
    {
        arrayId[count] = rand() % 2000 + 1;             
        arrayAges[count] = rand() % (30 + 1 - 18) + 18;
```

}

```
    for (p = 0; p < 1000; p++)
    {
        printf("%d.ID Number: %ld       Age: %d\n",p+1, arrayId[p], arrayAges[p]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1.ID Number: 1467       Age: 27
2.ID Number: 1316       Age: 21
3.ID Number: 1213       Age: 19
4.ID Number: 171       Age: 29
5.ID Number: 661       Age: 21
6.ID Number: 297       Age: 27
7.ID Number: 853       Age: 23
8.ID Number: 67       Age: 29
9.ID Number: 500       Age: 20
10.ID Number: 274       Age: 24
11.ID Number: 821       Age: 25
12.ID Number: 355       Age: 19
13.ID Number: 1797       Age: 23
14.ID Number: 1036       Age: 30
15.ID Number: 1637       Age: 18
16.ID Number: 385       Age: 22
17.ID Number: 1574       Age: 24
18.ID Number: 1305       Age: 20
19.ID Number: 1658       Age: 24
20.ID Number: 794       Age: 29
21.ID Number: 1758       Age: 24
22.ID Number: 1239       Age: 27
23.ID Number: 989       Age: 30
24.ID Number: 1449       Age: 22
25.ID Number: 1390       Age: 26
26.ID Number: 1731       Age: 25
27.ID Number: 1465       Age: 26
28.ID Number: 792       Age: 20
29.ID Number: 1974       Age: 24
30.ID Number: 1674       Age: 23
31.ID Number: 533       Age: 19
32.ID Number: 1078       Age: 28
33.ID Number: 571       Age: 25
34.ID Number: 48       Age: 20
35.ID Number: 115       Age: 19
36.ID Number: 345       Age: 24
.
.
.

979.ID Number: 35       Age: 30
980.ID Number: 965       Age: 29
981.ID Number: 457       Age: 26
982.ID Number: 615       Age: 24
983.ID Number: 667       Age: 26
984.ID Number: 1381       Age: 19
985.ID Number: 1032       Age: 20
986.ID Number: 534       Age: 26
987.ID Number: 1372       Age: 27
988.ID Number: 1299       Age: 24
989.ID Number: 1463       Age: 24
990.ID Number: 880       Age: 18
991.ID Number: 1928       Age: 28
992.ID Number: 867       Age: 23
993.ID Number: 1580       Age: 29
994.ID Number: 917       Age: 18
995.ID Number: 237       Age: 28
996.ID Number: 384       Age: 19
997.ID Number: 356       Age: 20
998.ID Number: 327       Age: 27
999.ID Number: 1768       Age: 18
1000.ID Number: 148       Age: 27

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.832 s
Press any key to continue.
```

it'll also help you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));             // generates the random numbers

    int i = 0, x, p, count;

     int arrayId[1000];      // array that holds the ID's of 1000 students
    char arrayAges[1000];        // array that holds the ages of 1000 students

    for (count = 0; count < 1000; count++) // Init the "age" and "id" arrays
    {
        //arrayId[count] = rand() % 2000 + 1;              // ID range 0001 - 2000
        arrayId[count] =rand() % (2000 + 1 - 1) + 1;
        arrayAges[count] = rand() % (30 + 1 - 18) + 18;   // Age range 18 - 30
    }

    while(i<1000){
        int r=rand() % (2000 + 1 - 0001) + 0001;

        for (x = 0; x < i; x++)
        {
            if(arrayId[x]==r){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(x==i){
            arrayId[i++]=r;
        }
    }

    for (p = 0; p < 1000; p++)
    {
        printf("%d.ID Number: %ld       Age: %d\n",p+1, arrayId[p], arrayAges[p]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Use this code"* or *"Try this"* are not helpful answers. Make an effort, in clear and understandable language, of what was wrong in the original code, and why you made the choices you did in offering corrections. That will make your answer not only helpful here, but helpful to other people with similar questions that end up here.